# drop hour,min,sec from timestemp?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I want to convert a date from sas, 14487, to 1999-08-31.

How can I convert the current results '1999-08-31 00:00:00' to '1999-08-31'?
I've tried ser.normalize(). But it doesn't help.

```
ser = pd.to_timedelta(14487, unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')
ser.normalize()
```

yield

```
Timestamp('1999-08-31 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`normalize` just resets the time to midnight (according to [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html)).

You can use `strftime` (see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html)). Also, [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is a list of the format specifiers you can use.

```
ser = pd.to_timedelta(14487, unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')
ser.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

outputs

```
'1999-08-31'
```

Comment: thanks.@Alex  any idea why .normalize() doesn't work?

Comment: @user7153 Welcome! Updated post to answer this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it in a datetime.date format:

```
(pd.to_timedelta(14487, unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')).date()
#Out: 
#datetime.date(1999, 8, 31)
```